# How to add URL value to form on new page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I've got a primary and secondary web page. The primary page has inputs where the user would initially enter information. The secondary page is giving me a list of values from mysql. I would like my user to be able to click a link for one of these values and open up the primary page with values returned in the correct input. Is there any way to click an href link and have the primary page inputs pick up the php variables? The primary page inputs are already echoing the correct variables. Currently, if a link is selected it opens the primary page without any data in the inputs. Any help is greatly appreciated, my code so far is below:

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($d_id); ?>" //example input value on primary page


function submit_form() //javascript
{
document.getElementById("submitform").submit();
}

// PHP
$creationdate = 'September 2015';
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Shop_Information WHERE creation_date=? ORDER BY shop_id DESC") or die(mysqli_error($sql->db_link));
$sql->bind_param('s', $creationdate);
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();
$num_of_rows=$sql->num_rows;
$sql->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4, $col5, $col6, $col7, $col8, $col9, $col10, $col11, $col12, $col13, $col14, $col15, $col16, $col17, $col18, $col19, $col20, $col21, $col22, $col23, $col24, $col25, $col26, $col27, $col28, $col29, $col30, $col31, $col32, $col33, $col34, $col35, $col36, $col37, $col38, $col39, $col40, $col41, $col42, $col43);
echo "<b><th><font size='5'>All dealer Mystery Shops.</font></th></b>";
echo "<hr> <br>";
while($sql->fetch()) 
{
    $d_region = $col3;
    $d_zone = $col4;
    $d_district = $col5;
    $d_id = $col6;
    $d_name = $col7;
    $d_url = $col8;
    $d_num_1 = $col9;
    $c_name = $col10;
    $c_email = $col11;
    $c_n_preferred = $col12;
    $c_incentive1 = $col13;
    $c_flag = $col14;
    $l_name = $col15;
    $c_date = $col16;
    $s_date = $col17;
    $d_called = $col18;
    $t_called = $col19;
    $c_q_1 = $col20;
    $c_q_2 = $col21;
    $c_q_3 = $col22;
    $c_q_4 = $col23;
    $c_q_5 = $col24;
    $c_q_6 = $col25;
    $c_q_7 = $col26;
    $c_q_8 = $col27;
    $c_q_9 = $col28;
    $c_q_10 = $col29;
    $c_q_11 = $col30;
    $c_q_12 = $col31;
    $c_q_13 = $col32;
    $c_q_14 = $col33;
    $c_q_15 = $col34;
    $c_ec_1 = $col35;
    $c_p_1 = $col36;
    $c_p_2 = $col37;
    $d_appt = $col38;
    $t_appt = $col39;
    $d_appt_cancelled = $col40;
    $comments = $col41;
    $c_q_16 = $col42;
    $c_q_17 = $col43;
    $shop_check = "update_shop";
    $sh_id = $col1;
    If($c_p_1 != "" && $c_p_2 != "")
    {$c_p_1 = "Yes";}
    elseif($c_p_1 == "" || $c_p_2 == "")
    {$c_p_1 = "No";}

    echo "<b>Dealer ID:</b> " . $d_id . " - <b>Dealer Name:</b> " . $d_name . " - <b>Mystery Shop ID:</b> " . $sh_id . " - <b>Graded?:</b> " . $c_p_1 . "<a href='/URL.php' id='submitform' onclick='submit_form();' target='_blank'>Select</a>" . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Sure, it is achievable via JS and some AJAX callings! What the researches you made about it showed you so far?

Comment: you can pass the value like this with href `<a href='url.php?id=".$id."'>` and at `url.php` can fetch the value from link with `$_GET` like `$linkid = $_GET["id"];`

Comment: Hey thanks Shehary! What if I am already using the form to POST instead of GET?

Comment: Sorry I should be a little more specific. I am current posting data from the primary page in an if-elseif format. How can I integrate a GET statement to evaluate these posts into that php? I added the GET statements to an else evaluation and it works when opening the primary page from the secondary page, but posting data from the primary page no longer works

Comment: You could change it to $_REQUEST on the receiving page. that would accept either post or get

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everybody, I figured it out. Code snippets below:

Here is the href I used to post the string to URL

```
echo "<b>Dealer ID:</b> " . "<a href='/URL.php?dealer_id=".$d_id."&dealer_url=".$d_url."&dealer_name=".$d_name."&Region=".$d_region."&RO_Open=".$d_zone."&RO_Number=".$d_district."&number1=".$d_num_1."&first_name=".$c_name."&customer_email=".$c_email."&number_preferred=".$c_n_preferred."&customer_incentive1=".$c_incentive1."&customer_flag=".$c_flag."&list_name=".$l_name."&creation_date=".$c_date."&sale_date=".$s_date."&date_called=".$d_called."&time_called=".$t_called."&call_question_1=".$c_q_1."&call_question_2=".$c_q_2."&call_question_3=".$c_q_3."&call_question_4=".$c_q_4."&call_question_5=".$c_q_5."&call_question_6=".$c_q_6."&call_question_7=".$c_q_7."&call_question_8=".$c_q_8."&call_question_9=".$c_q_9."&call_question_10=".$c_q_10."&call_question_11=".$c_q_11."&call_question_12=".$c_q_12."&call_question_13=".$c_q_13."&call_question_14=".$c_q_14."&call_question_15=".$c_q_15."&call_question_ec_1=".$c_ec_1."&call_penalties_1=".$c_p_1."&call_penalties_2=".$c_p_2."&date_appointment=".$d_appt."&time_appointment=".$t_appt."&date_appointment_cancelled=".$d_appt_cancelled."&comments=".$comments."&call_question_16=".$c_q_16."&call_question_17=".$c_q_17."&shop_type=".$shop_check."' target='_blank'>".$d_id."</a>" . " - <b>Dealer Name:</b> " . $d_name2 . " - <b>Mystery Shop ID:</b> " . $sh_id . " - <b>Graded?:</b> " . $c_p_3 . "<br>";
```

Then in my main page, I used the following to evaluate and then call each variable so that my POST still worked:

```
if(empty($_GET['dealer_id']) == FALSE)
{
$d_id = $_GET['dealer_id'];
etc,etc,etc
}
```